# Android : Stop android service when other full screen apps are running

Tags: android, facebook, android-service

I am trying to create an app very much similar to Facebook messanger, where you get chat pop-ups. 
But facebook messanger doest not pop up when there are full screen apps / games are running. I am also trying to achieve the same. Can anyone tell me how to stop service when games like subway-surfers or any other full screen apps are running?

Here is facebook messenger setting screen
[image]

Comment: do you have solution for this?

Comment: @Wayne Sorry, but still looking for an answer